# What is wrong with this Query ? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to create 3 tables and join them with foreign keys. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I have no idea where is a mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
       Student_Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       Name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
       Surname VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
       Date_of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
       Phone INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       Email VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       Course_Id INT
       FOREIGN KEY (Course_Id) REFERENCES Course (Course_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
       Course_Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       Student_Id INT NOT NULL,
       Teacher_Id INT NOT NULL,
       Category VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
       FOREIGN KEY (Student_Id) REFERENCES Students (Student_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Teachers (
       Teacher_Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       Name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
       Surname VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
       Phone INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       Salary INT NOT NULL,
       Course_Id INT NOT NULL, 
       FOREIGN KEY (Teacher_Id) REFERENCES Course (Teacher_Id)
    );
```

I should create a Foreign Key to join all three tables.
I get this error every time: relation "course" does not exist
I can't find where is the mistake. Please help.

Comment: You can't reference the course table before you create it. You need to change the order of the CREATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you are attempting to crate a many-to-many (M:M) between `Students` and `Teachers` with `Course` as the resolution table. You are close, however, your definition sets up bi-directional relationships. This is normally not necessary. Define `Students` and `Teachers` without the FK to `Course`. Then define `Course` with a FK to each.

```
create table students (
       student_id     serial       primary key
     , name           varchar (20) not null
     , surname        varchar (30) not null
     , date_of_birth  date         not null
     , phone          int          not null unique
     , email          varchar(225) not null unique
);

create table teachers (
       teacher_id     serial       primary key      
     , name           varchar (20) not null
     , surname        varchar (30) not null
     , phone          int          not null unique
     , salary         int          not null
    );
    

   create table course (
       course_id    serial       primary key      
     , student_id   int          not null
     , teacher_id   int          not null
     , category     varchar (30) not null
     , foreign key (student_id)  references students (student_id)
     , foreign key (teacher_id)  references teachers (teacher_id) 
     , unique      (student_id, teacher_id)
);
```

If you **must** define bi-directional FK in `Students` and `Teachers` then create the tables without the FK then use [alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html) after `Course` is defined to add the FK and make them `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. *Necessary for eventual Inserts*.

```
alter table teachers add column course_id int references course(course_id) deferrable initially deferred;
alter table students add column course_id int references course(course_id) deferrable initially deferred;
```